# How can i deploy kubernetes for trial purpose? (sandbox kind of environment)

Tags: installation, kubernetes

Links suggested i use minikube to install kubernetes. However i am confused if i should install this on my ubuntu host machine or on the vm provisioned with virtual box running on this host machine.
I want to know the pre-requisites for the install and how to go about it. 
I am a newbie to kubernetes and pretty confused on how to go about it.

Comment: It will create its own VM to run Kubernetes in, so just do it on normal host machine. Specify VM type you want to use if need be.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks a lot that cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Kubernetes right away with Minikube. It will take just a few minutes to see Kubernetes running on your laptop or desktop. I tried it on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. I put it here https://gitlab.com/abushoeb/kubernetes/ but for your convenience, you can just follow the following steps:

### How to install Kubernetes

#### You need to install 3 components

- Virtualbox https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-virtualbox-on-ubuntu/
- Kubectl https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/
- Minikube https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube

Install Virtual Box

`$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list (add followin line to your sources.list if you haven't already)
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1`

Install Kubectl

`$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
$ chmod +x ./kubectl
$ sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

Install Minikube

`$ curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v0.20.0/minikube-linux-amd64
$ chmod +x minikube
$ sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/`

Minikube Commands

`start k8 cluster $ minikube start
or start specific version of k8 $ minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.5.2"
or start with a flag enabled $ minikube start --kubernetes-version="v1.5.3" --extra-config kubelet.EnableCustomMetrics=true
enable any addon e.g. heapster $ minikube addons enable heapster
see all k8 versions $ minikube get-k8s-versions
see minikube status $ minikube status
access k8 dashboard $ minikube dashboard (this will open your browser)
stop minikube $ minikube stop`

Reference

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases
- https://rominirani.com/tutorial-getting-started-with-kubernetes-on-your-windows-laptop-with-minikube-3269b54a226

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. However i seem to have issues when accessing the minikube dashboard. I get Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet. Do you have any suggestion to tackle this issue?

Comment: Is the Kubernetes running perfectly? You can check it by running $ kubectl get all --all-namespaces. If you see all pods are running (no pending pods) then you can assume your K8 is running fine. If not then make sure K8 is running smoothly before launching the dashboard. If your dashboard is still the same then go to the dashboard container and check the logs. It must give you some clue.

Comment: I think you have proxy issue. Just add your minikube ip to NO_PROXY ($ export NO_PROXY=$no_proxy,192.168.99.100). Here I assume your minikube ip is 192.168.99.100.

Comment: Kubectl get all --all-namespaces shows all the pods in ContainerCreating state and nothing in ready.

Comment: Then Kubernetes is not running correctly. At the beginning, it shows ContainerCreating but as soon as they are running, the status should be running, not ContainerCreating.

Comment: Yes that's something that i am thinking. Any suggestions on how i shoudl go about debugging it? I am completely new to Kubernetes and docker.

Answer (score 1):

Minikube already provides a VM with K8s installed. In this sense, with Minikube, you do not need to install anything. If your aim is to test how to work with Kubernetes (i.e. deploying pods, services, volumes...), then Minikube is for you. If, on the contrary, you want to experiment how to actually install Kubernetes (i.e. install kubelet, the API server...) then you will need to find another alternative, like for example sinning up several Ubuntu VMs and follow the installation documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/)